# Cannot get VersionControlServer service from TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I have a console application, which needs to download some files from source control (TFS). But when using the code below, the `VersionControlServer` service is null. Due to this, I cannot download the files I need.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(UrlSite));
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
bool hasAuthenticated = tpc.HasAuthenticated; // true
var versionControl2 = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>(); // null 
var buildServer2 = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>(); // successful initialization
var workItemStore2 = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>(); // successful initialization
```

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar but instantiate the TfsTeamProjectCollection slightly differently and this works from a cmdline app in our environment:

```
string collection = @"http://TFSSERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
var tfsServer = new Uri(collection);
var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsServer);
var versionControl2 = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var buildServer2 = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();
var workItemStore2 = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Comment: What part did not work? Did you find your URL to the tfs DefaultCollection and set that in the first line?